# Should [config] be a synonym for [configuration-files]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Stack Overflow currently has two tags for "configuration files", and I was wondering if one should be made into a synonym for the other. Both tags basically describe configuration files that initialize settings for programs (bold emphasis mine):

- [config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config)

  #### Excerpt

  > Config files configure the initial settings for some computer programs

  #### Description

  > **[Configuration files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file), or config files configure the initial settings for some computer programs.** They are used for user applications, server processes and operating system settings. They may be considered a simple database.

  #### Number of questions tagged: 1,759
- [configuration-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration-files)

  #### Excerpt

  > Files that configure the initial settings for some computer programs.

  #### Description

  > In computing, **configuration files, or config files configure the initial settings for some computer programs.** They are used for user applications, server processes and operating system settings. The files are often written in ASCII (rarely UTF-8) and line-oriented, with lines terminated by a newline or carriage return/line feed pair, depending on the operating system. They may be considered a simple database.

  #### Questions tagged: 1,145

If one should be made a synonym for the other, I think "configuration-files" should be the canonical tag, because it's more descriptive than simply "config", which is both a noun (configuration file) and a verb (to "configure" something).

Comment: Frankly, I think both should just be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

I think [config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config) should be deleted. Like you said, it's ambiguous as it could refer to *configuration file* or *act of configuring* something.

I think tags should have clear names so that you don't have to check the tag description.

Whether [configuration-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration-files) warrants its own tag is completely different can of worms.

Comment: I'm not so sure that "config" can really be considered to be a verb anymore (maybe I just got that idea in my head because I work with Git too much and you configure stuff with the `git config` command), but otherwise, I agree that tags should have clear names, so that you don't have to check their descriptions. I'm sure new users don't bother with that.

Comment: Maybe there should be a tag specifically for .Net's .config file format? I don't know if "config" is often used in that sense, but having a more specific and clear tag seem better.

Comment: @Cupcake When was `config` a verb?  That would be `configure`

Comment: @Izkata like I said, I work with Git a lot and often do `git config <setting> <value>`, so "config" is often associated (in my mind) with "to configure", even if that is not actually correct.

Answer (score 5):

Both tags should go. There's just too many different ways of storing and parsing configuration files as programmers in a boat. Just try to separate all the text and binary ways to store the configuration of a program. The only useful question "what configuration file format should I use?" that could have the tag, is useless for SO.

Let them burn...

Comment: I think there can be some generic issues with *configuration-files*, like how to synchronize the file with the *in memory* configuration.  It can also relate to *serialization*, etc.  Although in the current form, it seems to deal mostly with specific language configuration files, as opposed to general techniques for implementing them.